# How to handle "the_terms" inside loop

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, terms

I have been searching google but I am really confused. I am trying to display the terms of the taxonomy assigned to the post. I am using `the_terms($post->ID, 'locations');`. The custom taxonomy is hierarchical.

Example: 3 terms assigned to post: `USA(parent) > FL(direct child of "USA") > Miami(direct child of "FL")`. What I get: `FL, Miami, USA` which means the terms are being displayed in alphabetical order. I want them to be displayed like: `Miami, FL, USA`. Can this be achieved? I would also like to remove the anchors from the terms and `strip_tags(the_terms($post->ID, 'locations'))` doesn't seem to work.

While searching google some people use `get_terms()` some other `get_the_terms` and others `the_terms` which is what I use and seems to work - output the terms. What is the difference between those functions? Am I using the right one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your first question

> What is the difference between those functions

- [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) returns an array of terms objects that belongs to a specific taxonomy
- [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) returns an array of terms belonging to a post
- [`the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/) displays an HTML formatting string of term names belonging to a post

Because you need your terms not hyperlinked and ordered according to parent, I believe [`wp_get_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/) will be a better option here. `wp_get_object_terms()` also returns an array of terms belonging to a post, but is more flexible. You do pay for this flexibility though as you make an extra db call per post.

With this all in mind, you can try the following: (*All code is untested*)

```
$args = [
    'orderby' => 'parent', 
    'order'   => 'DESC' 
];
$terms  = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'locations', $args );
$names  = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name' );
$output = implode( ', ', $names );
echo $output;
```

Comment: Feel free to leave me a comment if you are not clear about something ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works however it seems to ignore `'order'   => 'DSC'`. It outputs "USA, FL, Miami" while I want this reversed "Miami, FL, USA".

Comment: Nevermind, I am stupid. I used "DSC" instead of "DESC". Thanks a ton for your help Pieter!

Comment: Hahaha, no problem, was just about to post `DESC`. Glad it worked. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
get_the_terms(int|object $post, string $taxonomy)
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/
  or

```
get_terms(array|string $args = array(), array $deprecated = '')
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

because

```
the_terms()
```

echo/prints the results

and

```
 get_the_terms() //or
 get_terms()
```

only get value and save it to variable or memory.

A possible example is

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    $term= get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category' );
    echo 'Category: '.$term;
}
```

You may need to use another loop to handle $terms if there or more than 1 object in any case.

Comment: I want to display the_terms inside the loop... I am not trying to list all the taxonomy terms.

Comment: Ok you can get and then echo terms inside loop.. If  you are in wordpress default post loop then you can do it more easily. just post the_terms();  you don't need to provide any parameter other than custom taxonomy. 
I will suggest you to share your code and scenario in detail here so others can help you in effective way

Comment: It just displays the word "Array".

Comment: Ok. Yes it will be do this 
      $trm=the_term(); 
      print_r($trm)   

and then share your result here.

Comment: I understand nothing. Anyway, thanks for you contribution.